# ZF2 Lucene query returns nothing - same query in Luke returns expected result

Tags: lucene, zend-framework2

In ZF2 I am using the following code to generate a Lucene query:

```
    $query = new Lucene\Search\Query\Boolean();

    $term = new Lucene\Index\Term($search->type, 'type');
    $subqueryTerm = new Lucene\Search\Query\Term($term);
    $query->addSubquery($subqueryTerm, true);

    $term = new Lucene\Index\Term('[+<= ' . $search->purchase_value . ']', 'min_price');
    $subqueryTerm = new Lucene\Search\Query\Term($term);
    $query->addSubquery($subqueryTerm, true); // required

    $term = new Lucene\Index\Term('[' . $search->purchase_value . ' >=]', 'max_price');
    $subqueryTerm = new Lucene\Search\Query\Term($term);
    $query->addSubquery($subqueryTerm, true); // required
```

which produces the following query:

```
+(type:Buying) +(min_price:[+<= 160.00]) +(max_price:[160.00 >=])
```

When I run this query in ZF2 (`$hits  = $index->find($query);`) I get an empty array returned, however when I use [Luke](https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/) to manually run the query against the index it returns the result I am expecting.

What do I need to change in my code to make it return the same results as Luke?

I am using the default analyser for both systems:

- Luke: `org.apache.lucene.analysis.KeywordAnalyzer`
- ZF2: (which I think is) `\ZendSearch\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\Text`

Do I need to use a different QueryParser?

Comment: Thinking it might be related to the length of the number I have used `str_pad($input, 10, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)` so the stored value is similar to `0000432.10`. I am also formatting the query in the same way. Again, it works in Luke but not for ZF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for the term "[+<= 160.00]" in the field min_price. You are *not* creating a range query. I don't quite get what you mean by using a different QueryParser, you aren't using a QueryParser at all, you are using the API to construct your queries. You need to use a [range search](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.query-api.html#zend.search.lucene.queries.range):

```php
$term = new Lucene\Index\Term($search->purchase_value, 'min_price');
$subqueryRange = new Lucene\Search\Query\Range(null, $term, true);
$query->addSubquery($subqueryRange, true);

$term = new Lucene\Index\Term($search->purchase_value, 'max_price');
$subqueryRange = new Lucene\Search\Query\Range($term, null, true);
$query->addSubquery($subqueryRange, true);
```

I'm assuming here, by the way, that "+<=" is meant to be query syntax for less than or equal to.  I'm not familiar with anything in lucene that supports that sort of syntax.  An open ended range, as shown, would be the correct thing to use.